# How to avoid next line in BASH script

Tags: bash

I am trying to read table names and index names from two different text files and then building the sql files which can be used to do the de-fragmentation and index re-building.
It is working fine as of now but generated sql file contains next line after table/index name.
PFB script and sample outputs.

BASH Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export logfile=/tmp/logfile.log
export tablenamesfile=/tmp/tablenames.txt
export tabledefragfile=/tmp/tabledefrag.sql
export indexnamesfile=/tmp/indexnames.txt
export indexrebuildfile=/tmp/indexrebuild.sql

while read line; do echo "alter table $line enable row movement;" >> $tabledefragfile; echo "alter table $line shrink space;" >> $tabledefragfile; echo "alter table $line disable row movement;" >> $tabledefragfile; done < $tablenamesfile
echo "Please check sql file - $(readlink -f $tabledefragfile)"

while read line; do echo "alter index $line rebuild parameters('tablespace=TBS_3');" >> $indexrebuildfile; done < $indexnamesfile
echo "Please check sql file - $(readlink -f $indexrebuildfile)"

exit
```

Current output in tabledefrag.sql

```
alter table APA_DS_DATASTORE
 enable row movement;
alter table APA_DS_DATASTORE
 shrink space;
alter table APA_DS_DATASTORE
 disable row movement;
```

Current output in indexrebuild.sql

```
alter index APA_DS_DATASTORE_PK
 rebuild parameters('tablespace=TBS_3');
alter index APA_FS_DEFAULT_FSENTRY_IDX
 rebuild parameters('tablespace=TBS_3');
alter index APA_FS_DEFAULT_FSENTRY_IDX
 rebuild parameters('tablespace=TBS_3');
```

Expected output:

```
alter index APA_DS_DATASTORE_PK rebuild parameters('tablespace=TBS_3');
alter index APA_FS_DEFAULT_FSENTRY_IDX rebuild parameters('tablespace=TBS_3');
alter index APA_FS_DEFAULT_FSENTRY_IDX rebuild parameters('tablespace=TBS_3');
```

Comment: @alecxs input is taken from two different text files which contain table/index names like below. Each table/index name is on new line...
APA_DS_DATASTORE_PK
APA_FS_DEFAULT_FSENTRY_IDX

Comment: hm.. right, understand the issue now. don't know if that is expected but seems `read` does save `\n` as last byte into `$line`, so the proper way would be to tell `read` not to do that (but i don't know how). as workaround you can `echo` without quotes, or remove the last byte (in general `${line%?}` or explicit `${line//$'\n'}`)

Comment: you can edit your question and add the output of `printf "%s" "$line" | hexdump -C` for debugging purposes

Comment: @alecxs issue is resolved by putting `while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r line`. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` has a newline by default. You should use `printf` instead.

You'll also need to avoid the newline coming from the file: `while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r LINE`

Comment: printf didn't resolve the issue. My issue is that there is new line after I print table name using $line in echo. Remaining part of the statement for e.g. 'enable row movement;' should be printed in the same line.

Comment: `while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r line` should fix it. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I just added `while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r line`. 
'echo' remains as it is. So, maybe you can remove the suggestion to use 'printf' from answer. Now, I am getting the desired output. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You would be well advised to use `printf` in place of `echo` to avoid issues in future - even of its not the cause of this problem.